# Loop in Field name

Tags: django

I am trying to define a class with its different fields please someone can help me loop on the index of the field so that it is clean ?

```
class Tabletarif (models.Model):
age_duree = models.CharField (max_length = 4)
U_20 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_19 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_18 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_17 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_16 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_15 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_14 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_13 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_12 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_11 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_10 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_9 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_8 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_7 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_6 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
U_5 = models.FloatField (default = 0)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a `for` loop in the `class`:

```
class Tabletarif (models.Model):
    age_duree = models.CharField (max_length = 4)
    for i in range(20, 4, -1):
        locals()[f'U_{i}'] = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

But this look really ugly. Usually what is done is to "linearize" the data, so with an extra model that refers to the `Tabletarif` and also has a reference to the `U_…` it is working with, so something like:

```
class TableTarif(models.Model):
    age_duree = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class TableTarifItem(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField()
    table_tarif = models.ForeignKey(TableTarif, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.